# How can I calculate a block number of where a word is located on disk?

Tags: linux, string, bash

I want to find out what block number the word "word" is using. I know blocks start at 0, so I thought that adding 2114+1 would be my answer, but it's not...

```
user@host:~$ strings -td dump.dd|grep "word"
2114 __strtsuper your word is stored here
```

I know -td brings me back the offset in decimal, but how can I calculate the block number? What do I need to do with the 2114 number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strings` offsets are in `bytes`.
A disk block is composed by a group of `bits`, commonly `512` (and on bigger disks `4096`).

So, you must know the block size of your disk, convert to bytes (1 byte = 8 bits), and divide the `strings` offset by that number.